# cross sum operation in Haskell

Tags: haskell, math, recursion

I need to determine a recursive function crosssum :: Int -> Int in Haskell to calculate the cross sum of positive numbers. I am not allowed to use any functions from the hierarchical library besides (:), (>), (++), (<), (>=), (<=), div, mod, not (&&), max, min, etc.

```
crosssum :: Int -> Int 
cross sum x = if x > 0 
          then x `mod` 10 
          + x `div` 10 + crosssum x 
          else 0
```

so whenever I fill in e.g. crosssum 12 it says 'thread killed'. I do not understand how to get this right. I would appreciate any ideas. Thx

Comment: Usually, in defining recursive functions, you change the argument when you perform the recursive call. E.g. `f x = 1 + f (x-1)`. Instead, above you use something like `f x = 1 + f x` which will recurse forever.

Comment: This does not look like valid Haskell code. Please *copy and paste* the latest version of your code - do not type it in, as you may make typos when you do so. Also, if you have more than one function, please include all the functions.

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems with your code is that `x` is not reduced (or changed somehow) when it's passed as an argument to the recursive call of `crosssum`. That's why your program never stops.

The modified code:

```
crosssum :: Int -> Int
crosssum x = if x > 0
             then x `mod` 10 + crosssum (x `div` 10)
             else 0
```

is going to have the following logic

```
crosssum 12 = 2 + (crosssum 1) = 2 + (1 + (crosssum 0)) = 2 + 1 + 0
```

By the way, Haskell will help you to avoid `if` condition by using pattern-matching to receive more readable code:

```
crosssum :: Int -> Int
crosssum 0 = 0
crosssum x =
  (mod x 10) + (crosssum (div x 10))
```

Answer (score 1):

divMod in Prelude is very handy, too. It's one operation for both `div` and `mod`, In fact for all 2 digit numbers `dm n = sum.sequence [fst,snd] $ divMod n 10`

```
cs 0 = 0;   cs n =  m+ cs d   where (d,m) = divMod n 10
```

cs will do any size number.